# BFS, wanting to find the longest path between nodes, reducing the findchildren-method

Tags: python, python-3.x, breadth-first-search

I've opened another thread with exactly this subject, but I think I posted too much code and I didn't really know where my problem was, now I think I have a better idea but still in need of help. What we have is a text-file with 3 letter words, only 3 letter words. I also have a Word (node) and queue-class. My findchildren-method is supposed to find, for one single word, all the children to this word, let's say I enter "fan", then I'm supposed to get something like ["kan","man"....etc]. The code is currently looking like this:

```
def findchildren(mangd,parent): 
    children=set()
    lparent=list(parent)
    mangd.remove(parent)
    for word in mangd:
        letters=list(word)
        count=0
        i=0
        for a in letters:
            if a==lparent[i]:
                count+=1
                i+=1
            else:
                i+=1
            if count==2:
                if word not in children:
                    children.add(word)
            if i>2:
                break
    return children
```

The code above, for findchildren is currently working fine, but, when I use it for my other methods (to implement the bfs-search) everything will take way too long time, therefore, I would like to gather all the children in a dictionary containing lists with the children. It feels like this assignment is out of my league right now, but is this possible to do? I tried to create something like this:

```
def findchildren2(mangd):
    children=[]
    for word in mangd:
        lparent=list(word)
        mangd.remove(word)
        letters=list(word)
        count=0
        i=0
        for a in letters:
            if a==lparent[i]:
                count+=1
                i+=1
            else:
                i+=1
            if count==2:
                if word not in children:
                    children.append(word)
            if i>2:
                break
    return children
```

I suppose my last try is simply garbage, I get the errormessage " Set changed size using iteration".

```
def findchildren3(mangd,parent):
    children=defaultdict(list)
    lparent=list(parent)
    mangd.remove(parent)
    for word in mangd:
        letters=list(word)
        count=0
        i=0
        for a in letters:
            if a==lparent[i]:
                count+=1
                i+=1
            else:
                i+=1
            if count==2:
                children[0].append(word)
            if i>2:
                break
    return children
```

Comment: Can you define _all the children to this word_ exactly?  From your example it sounds like works with a common suffix of length 2?  also should us sample input/output

Comment: all the children to "fan", is simply all the children to "fan" that is in my txt file, a children to "fan" is every word that shares two letters with "fan". These are swedish words, and it doesnt matter in which order they share two common letters, for example, "fbn" would be perfectly fine but my txt-file doesnt contain that word. 

What I want as output, is a dictionary containing lists with all the children to a word. Im hoping to be able to use this to speed up my other methods by simply gathering the children from this dictionary instead of calling findchildren all the time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are more efficient ways to do this (the below is O(n^2) so not great) but here is a simple algorithm to get you started:

```
import itertools
from collections import defaultdict

words = ['abc', 'def', 'adf', 'adc', 'acf', 'dec']
bigrams = {k: {''.join(x) for x in itertools.permutations(k, 2)} for k in words}
result = defaultdict(list)
for k, v in bigrams.iteritems():
    for word in words:
        if k == word:
            continue
        if len(bigrams[k] & bigrams[word]):
            result[k].append(word)
print result
```

Produces:

```
defaultdict(<type 'list'>, {'abc': ['adc', 'acf'], 'acf': ['abc', 'adf', 'adc'], 'adf': ['def', 'adc', 'acf'], 'adc': ['abc', 'adf', 'acf', 'dec'], 'dec': ['def', 'adc'], 'def': ['adf', 'dec']})
```

---

Here is a more efficient version with some commentary:

```
import itertools
from collections import defaultdict

words = ['abc', 'def', 'adf', 'adc', 'acf', 'dec']

# Build a map of {word: {bigrams}} i.e. {'abc': {'ab', 'ba', 'bc', 'cb', 'ac', 'ca'}}
bigramMap = {k: {''.join(x) for x in itertools.permutations(k, 2)} for k in words}

# 'Invert' the map so it is {bigram: {words}} i.e. {'ab': {'abc', 'bad'}, 'bc': {...}}
wordMap = defaultdict(set)
for word, bigramSet in bigramMap.iteritems():
    for bigram in bigramSet:
        wordMap[bigram].add(word)

# Create a final map of {word: {words}} i.e. {'abc': {'abc', 'bad'}, 'bad': {'abc', 'bad'}}
result = defaultdict(set)
for k, v in wordMap.iteritems():
    for word in v:
        result[word] |= v ^ {word}

# Display all 'childen' of each word from the original list
for word in words:
    print "The 'children' of word {} are {}".format(word, result[word])
```

Produces:

```
The 'children' of word abc are set(['acf', 'adc'])
The 'children' of word def are set(['adf', 'dec'])
The 'children' of word adf are set(['adc', 'def', 'acf'])
The 'children' of word adc are set(['adf', 'abc', 'dec', 'acf'])
The 'children' of word acf are set(['adf', 'abc', 'adc'])
The 'children' of word dec are set(['adc', 'def'])
```

Comment: Im extremely grateful for your help, I'll try to implement this to my BFS and see if I can make it a bit more effective, currently its very, very slow.

Comment: If I would like to, for example, call for the children of "abc", is there an easy way to do that ?

Comment: To make it fast the thing to do is reverse the dict so it maps `digram -> list [word]` i.e. `{'ab': ['abc', 'abd', 'acb']}` then you have all the words with two common letters in the list.

Comment: Sure, just do `print result['abc']` which gives `['adc', 'acf']`

Comment: Thank you Fujiapple, if I wasnt so new to the forum, I would rep you up as well of course!

Comment: @Krantz - no problem, your happiness is thanks enough :)

Comment: Im trying it out right now Fujiapple, is there a way to change permutations so that it will only find 2 of the letters, but they have to be on the right spot, for example, children to "fan" would be "ban","man" etc, but "ans" is not a child... Hope you understand what I mean

Comment: Would `fbn` be considered a child?  it shares two letters in common in matching positions or do they have to be consecutive letters?

Comment: yes, "fbn" would be a child, but for example, "ana" isnt supposed to be a child to "fan". They dont have to be in order, but they got to be in the right position

Comment: Added a solution as a new answer to keep in clean, if it suits you better pl,ease updated the accepted answer.  Probably a good idea to update the question as well so it reflects the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Solution (which is O(n^2) sadly) for the updated requirement in Python 3 (run it [here](https://repl.it/Cq11/0)):

from collections import defaultdict

```
words = ['fan', 'ban', 'fbn', 'ana', 'and', 'ann']

def isChildOf(a, b):
    return sum(map(lambda xy: xy[0] == xy[1], zip(a, b))) >= 2

result = defaultdict(set)
for word in words:
    result[word] = {x for x in words if isChildOf(word, x) and x != word}

# Display all 'childen' of each word from the original list
for word in words:
    print("The children of word {0} are {1}".format(word, result[word]))
```

Produces:

```
The 'children' of word fan are set(['ban', 'fbn'])
The 'children' of word ban are set(['fan'])
The 'children' of word fbn are set(['fan'])
The 'children' of word ana are set(['and', 'ann'])
The 'children' of word and are set(['ann', 'ana'])
The 'children' of word ann are set(['and', 'ana'])
```

The algorithm here is very simple and not very efficient but let me try to break it down.

The `isChildOf` function takes two words as input and does the following:

1. `zip`'s `a` & `b` together, here both are treated as iterables with each character being one 'item' in the iteration.  For example if `a` is `'fan'` and `b` is `'ban'` then `zip('fan', 'ban')` produces this list of pairs `[('f', 'b'), ('a', 'a'), ('n', 'n')]`
2. Next it uses the `map` function to apply the lambda function (a fancy name for an anonymous function) to *each item* in the list produced in step one.  The function simply takes the pair of input elements (i.e. `'f'` & `'b'`) and returns `True` if they match and `False` otherwise.  For our example this will result in `[False, True, True]` as the first pair of characters do not match but both the remaining pairs do match.
3. Finally the function runs the `sum` function on the list produced by step 2.  It so happens that `True` evaluates to `1` in Python and `False` to `0` and so the sum of our list is `2`.  We then simply return whether that number is greater than or equal to `2`.

The `for word in words` loop simply compares each input word against all other words and keeps the ones where `isChildOf` evaluates to `True` taking care not to add the word itself.

I hope that is clear!

Comment: I edited up there to see, is it possible to do something like that instead? Your solution is way more elegant but I dont really understand the code :/

Comment: That method I edited up there seem to do the trick, but I'm getting duplicates currently, and I would like to get all the words from my list immediately

Comment: Does this answer give you the result you need?  if so I'll break it down a bit to help you understand it.

Comment: The problem is that I cant run it, something wrong with the isChild (notice that im using python3). Since I dont really understand it that well, its hard for me. but when I look at your "produces" it seems to be working exactly how I want it to work.

Comment: Updated to work in Python 3.  Next time remember to add the `python-3.x` tag to the question :)

Comment: sorry for that :/ well, that is working for me, im unsure of how it works, but it works

Comment: Updated with a breakdown of how it works, hopefully you'll be able to understand and use as a learning opportunity.

Comment: Thanks again, I will try to understand your solution, looking a lot better than mine at least. Sorry for not using the python3 tag, ill keep that in mind for next time. I might return with another question :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/121616/discussion-between-fujiapple-and-krantz).